# Access url params on server-side nextjs, outside of a component

Tags: node.js, next.js

On a next.js project, I have a server-side rendered page that takes a query param, e.g.

`site.com/page?search=foo`

I'd like to access the url or url params `{search: "foo"}` on the server-side, *outside* of any Component. In my case this is needed to export metadata on the page. Ideal example:

```
const queryParams = {search: "foo"}
// ^ how do I actually get this

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  openGraph: {
    description: "this is a search for " + queryParams.search
  }
}

export default function Page() {
  return <div>content</div>
}
```

I see documentation for [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props), but afaict this only runs code inside, and then exports for the Component later - I can't `export const metadata` within that. Other documentation for `useRouter` or `window` do not work as those are client-side.